# Laravel Blade code always can't running well

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a little problem with Laravel Blade in Laravel version 5.2. Can someone tell me how to include a Blade template within a Blade template? I already try to include `welcome.blade.php`
by `@include('welcome')` but, I always get an error message.

Comment: Can you tell us path of welcome blade and exact error you are getting?

Comment: Do you  want to include your page in another page, or another page in your page?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to define a master page or main template what ever you say.
we create main.blade.php as template page .

```
 <html>
  <div class="row">
     @yield("content")
 </div>
```

the above code is our simple template page.

inside your welcome.blade.php write as below

```
 @extends("main")
  @section("content")
      your code 
  @stop
```

if welcome.blade.php is your template or master page do like below.

welcome.blade.php :

```
  <html>
  <div class="row">
     @yield("content")
 </div>
```

inside your other page you want use welcome page as template do as below :

```
   @extends("welcome")
  @section("content")
      your code 
  @stop
```